# Which opensource database satisfies all these requirements?

Tags: c, database, notifications, acid

1. Supports C API for reading and writing into the DB.
2. Support ACID transaction feature.
3. Support sending notifications if any change happens to DB state.

Finally it should be an open source.

Could someone suggest a open source database which supports all these above features.

Comment: A quick Google search would have given you this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_relational_database_management_systems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgres supports those features.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think I understand what you refer to in #3. If you mean triggers, [CUBRID](http://cubrid.org) could also do the job.